# Using OR operator in combination with Find function

Tags: matlab, matrix, find

I have this section of code. I want to find the closest node among the two sets of base stations (ABS and RBS). The way i am doing it is like this but the find function gives me an error. Both the distance matrices is of the same size.

```
closest_dist=min(distance_ua(iduser,:),distance_ur(iduser,:));
closest_node=(find(distance_ua(iduser,:)==closest_dist)) || (find(distance_ur(iduser,:)==closest_dist));
```

Comment: No, actually they are two different matrices. one is "distance_ua" and other is "distance_ur".

Answer (score 2):

`find` returns an array of index values and `||` only works for values which can be converted to logical scalars. An array of integers cannot be convert to a logical scalar.

```
[1 2 3] || [1 2 3]
```

> Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar
>   values.

If you want to use the logical OR, you're better off using `find` *after* the operation which would be performed directly on the logical arrays. Additionally, you'll want to use `|` instead of `||` to compare two logical arrays.

```
closest_node = find(distance_uid(iduser, :) == closest_dist | ...
                    distance_ur(iduser, :) == closest_dist);
```